Zpool scrub won't resume after reboot
Linux Mint 21.3
Linux version 6.5.0-26-generic
zfs-2.2.3-0ofthesun1
zfs-kmod-2.2.0-0ubuntu1~23.10.2

I've set up the zpool just fine, put some data on it and started a scrub. While this was in progress I rebooted the system. After that, zpool status shows me the scrub is paused. It won't resume automatically.
I've got another system with a similar setup, just on Mint 21.3 and the original zfs/kernel 5. There the scrub resumes right after reboot.
Comparing their setups didn't give me a clue, but I'm not that experienced to be able to compare 100%.
I can't seem to find the issue, any help greatly appreciated!

After I rebooted quite a few times, the scrub resumed. I can't figure out why.

if your issue is fixed, either accept an answer or add your own, but please accept or write one else we will be reminded until the end of the universum to solve your issue.

I actually thought it's obvious that this isn't solved.


Don't run random scrubs
Don't reboot in the middle of one

If you are running a scrub and plan to reboot your system in the middle of that process, you can pause a scrub "zpool scrub -p poolname" or you can stop it entirely "zpool scrub -s poolname".

Thanks for the answer but that isn't fitting to this topic at all. I understand your tips well but in my case, a reboot may happen. The scrub must not stay paused after the system is up again. I would like to understand behavior before I aim to script something down to check on my own.
